# Why is my jQuery script written in notepad++ not working on files stored locally?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to do a simple slider but that did not work, so i am copying one of code cademy, but it still qont work. 
 
I have used 4 different browsers all have the same problem, i can type in the box but wont post, and show below.

PLEASE HELP?

Html

```
     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link type='text/css' href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <textarea class="form-control status-box" rows="2" placeholder="What's on your mind?"></textarea>
    </div>
  </form>
  <div class="button-group pull-right">
    <p class="counter">140</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Post</a>
  </div>
  <ul class="posts">
  </ul>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

AMMENDED 
script.js

```
$(document).ready() {
$('.btn').click(function() {
    var post = $('.status-box').val()
        $('<li>').text(post).prependTo('posts');
});
};
```

THANK YOU ALL, this has been corrected and it now works :)

Comment: Are you opening the file directly or you mounted a local server (E.g: XAMPP, WAMP, something)? If you are opening the file directly, it's normal that it doesn't work. Otherwise, I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: why wouldn't the file work if I open it directly from my computer? I don't understand..

Comment: `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js` is a protocol-less url. That's designed so it allows the file to be loaded using the same protocol as the page you are vieweing. When you open the file directly, it will use the `file:` protocol. That is, you will be trying to open `file:///ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js`, which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`val` is a jQuery function ... you need `()` to invoke it so it returns the value of element. As your code stands now you are trying to set a function object as text.

You are also using incorrect selectors `$('btn')` and `$('status-box')` which are looking for non existent tags `<btn>` and `<status-box>`.

Add  dot prefix for both to represent class:

`$('.btn')` and `$('.status-box')`

Comment: I addition to this answer you can remove the definition of the `main` function (`var main = function() { /* ... */ };`), because you don't call it.

Answer (score 0):

As well as what's been mentioned in the other answer, I don't believe your main method is ever called. If it isn't called then the event handler isn't going to be attached.
The main method would be easier set up via jquery, so instead of:

```
var main = function() {
$('btn').click(function() {
    var post = $('status-box').val
        $('<li>').text(post).prependTo('.posts');
});
}
```

Just do:

```
$(function() {
  $('btn').click(function() {
      var post = $('status-box').val
          $('<li>').text(post).prependTo('.posts');
  });
});
```

Alternatively you could adjust your body tag as follows:

```
<body onload="main()">
```